# Staking Pools, How do they work? what are their machanics?

Tags: staking, validator

How do nomination pools work in the system, what are the mechanics and who controls the direction of those nominations? what are their mechanics?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Found information about pools in the website for those asking same question.

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-staking#4-rewards-mechanism

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).